# My push button code doesn't work properly

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano, code-review

I'm using an OLED display connected to a push button.  I am trying to get my display to show two different values independently  by using the push button to switch between them. Here is a snap of my code from the loop function:

```
    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    x=x+1;
  }    
  if (x == 1) {
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(0, 0);
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.print(T);
  display.print(" degree");
  display.display();
  display.print(x);

}
    else if (x == 2) {
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(0, 0);
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.print(perventage);
  display.print(" %");
  display.display();
  display.print(x);
}
    else  {
      x=1; 
      }


  delay(10);
}
```

x is defined as 1 initially out side the loop.
What happens is that when the circuit is turned on, the screen displays the value of T then what should happen is when I push the button it switches to the second value which is percentage, and I push again to go back to T. My issue is that the Arduino doesn't response to the push button all of the time sometimes it takes 1 click and other times it takes 6 or 8 fast clicks to switch between them and it doesn't stick to a specific number of pushes to switch.
What would you suggest me to change to fix it.

Edit: here is pic of my wiring diagram
[image: Wiring diagram]

Comment: How is your button wired?

Comment: It should switch between the values from 1 push as it's designed from the code, but In reality it rarely switches between values from 1 push, it takes 4,5,6,8 pushes just to get it to switch between values. I don't understand why it behave like that

Comment: Yes, that's what you said in your question. But I asked "How is your button wired?", not "Reiterate what you said in your question about how you want it to behave".

Comment: Please show a picture of how you have your button connected to the Arduino.

Comment: how i the push button connected to the oled display?

Comment: the picture shows that the pushbutton is not connected to any data lines

Comment: sorry I for got to add a wire from one of the top pins to pin number 2 in the picture, I have it connected on my breadboard circuit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One core problem is that you have a simple "If the button is HIGH then cycle through the numbers". The longer you hold the button the more times it will cycle through the numbers.  It's pure 50/50 chance that you happen to release the button on a different number to the one it started on.

Instead you need to look for a *change* in the state of the button. Has it changed from LOW to HIGH:

```
static uint8_t oldState = LOW;

uint8_t buttonState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);
if (buttonState != oldState) {
    oldState = buttonState;

    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
        // This only runs once at the moment of pressing
        // the button - not continuously while you're
        // holding the button in.
        // Cycle through your displays here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the raw button state without debouncing it, so you may be getting 2 (or 4, or ...) pulses so quickly - off the same button-push - that the display or your eye can't respond that quickly. Here is [Nick Gammon's tutorial on switches and buttons](http://www.gammon.com.au/switches), including debouncing.

Also make sure you use a pull-down resistor on the button input-pin. Floating inputs are noise and will give you a lot of false signals.